# Removing .html From URL Using Apache Config

Tags: html, apache, file, configuration

All questions I've found so far explain it using .htaccess, and Apache seems to want you to use the configuration file if you can, as it's faster and "better".

How do you remove .html from the URLs using the Apache configuration file? I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04.1 server with Apache2.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```